# Scrapy doesnt get products from an ecommerce site

Tags: scrapy

I try to learn Scrapy and I manage to crawl some sites and other I fail for example:
I try to crawl: http://www.polyhousestore.com/

I created a test spider that will get all the products in the page 
http://www.polyhousestore.com/catalogsearch/result/?cat=&q=lc+60

When I run the spider I get that it didn’t find any product.
Can someone help me understand what am I doing wrong, is it related to the CSS ::before and ::after ?
And how can I make it to work?

Spider code(that fail to get the products in the page)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class PolySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "poly"
    allowed_domains = ["polyhousestore.com"]
    start_urls = (
    'http://www.polyhousestore.com/catalogsearch/result/?cat=&q=lc+60',
    )
 def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    products =          sel.xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div')
    items = []
    if not products:
        print '-------------   No products  from sel.xpath'
    else:
        print '-------------   Found products ' + str(len(products))
```

Command line that I run and the output

> ```
> D:\scrapyProj\cmdProj>scrapy crawl poly
> 2016-01-19 10:23:16 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: cmdProj)
> 2016-01-19 10:23:16 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
> 2016-01-19 10:23:16 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE':    'cm
> dProj.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['cmdProj.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'cmdProj'}
> 2016-01-19 10:23:17 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider,    TelnetConsol
> e, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
> 2016-01-19 10:23:17 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:  HttpAuthMiddl
> eware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultH
> eadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMidd
> leware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
> 2016-01-19 10:23:17 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddlewa
> re, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
> 2016-01-19 10:23:17 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
> 2016-01-19 10:23:17 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
> 2016-01-19 10:23:17 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped   0 i
> tems (at 0 items/min)
> 2016-01-19 10:23:17 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on   127.0.0.1:6023
> 2016-01-19 10:23:17 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET    http://www.polyhousestore
> .com/catalogsearch/result/?cat=&q=lc+60> (referer: None)
> -------------   No products  from sel.xpath
> 2016-01-19 10:23:18 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
> 2016-01-19 10:23:18 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
> {'downloader/request_bytes': 254,
> 'downloader/request_count': 1,
> 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
> 'downloader/response_bytes': 16091,
> 'downloader/response_count': 1,
> 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
> 'finish_reason': 'finished',
> 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 19, 8, 23, 18, 53000),
> 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
> 'log_count/INFO': 7,
> 'response_received_count': 1,
> 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
> 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
> 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
> 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
> 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 19, 8, 23, 17, 376000)}
> 2016-01-19 10:23:18 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
> ```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I look at the URL given in your question with Chrome I see only 2 `div` tags in the `body` of the site. This means scrapy sees these `div` tags too. However you want to access the 4th, which does not exist so your search returns no elements.

If I open a scrapy shell and execute a count on the `div` tags on the body I get **2** in return:

```
[<Selector xpath='count(/html/body/div)' data=u'2.0'>]
```

This above is the same as

```
 len(response.xpath('/html/body/div'))
```

All this means you have to modify your query to get all the products. If you need the 4 elements in the site, try:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="item-inner"]')
```

As you can see you do not need to wrap the response into a selector with scrapy anymore.

Comment: THanks for the answer

Comment: I try to understand where I went wrong? I got the path by copy it from the chrome inspect, so I don't understand why it didn't work for me ? and from were did you got the item-inner I didn't find it?

Comment: I simply opened the Chrome inspector with your site, selected one of the items and it was in a `div` with `item-inner` class. Of course there is a layer of `div` tags around the item contents so you can refine your XPath but I just wanted to show where to search.

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer helped feel free to accept it.